# exercise and I do not know if I am correct

Tags: sequences-and-series

prove that the following function is continuous $\dfrac{e^x}{e^{5x}+e^x+1}$ so i follow the definition of continouos and I get this:
$\left|\dfrac{e^x}{e^{5x}+e^x+1}-\dfrac{e^{x_{0}}}{e^{5x_{0}}+e^{x_{0}}+1}\right|$
then $\left|\dfrac{e^{x+5x_{0}}+e^{x+x_{0}}+e^{x}-e^{5x+x_{0}}-e^{x+x_0}+e^{x_{0}}}{(e^{5x}+e^x+1)(e^{5x_{0}}+e^{x_{0}}+1)}\right|$ but I don't know if I should apply the ln or what I should do, because I was thinking of taking out the common factor $e^{x-x_0}$ and but I do not not if I can do that

Comment: An option might be to check that $f(x)=e^{x}$ and $g(x)= e^{5x} + e^x + 1 $ are continuous with $g(x)>0$, then use a theorem if you've covered it that states $f/g$ is continuous if such a thing has been made available to you. You can also just use the properties of limits here due to the form and properties of the function.

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title—one that describes the content of your question.  Of COURSE you don't know if you're correct... that's why you're asking a question!

Comment: The limit definition of continuity is primarily important for demonstrating facts such as: if $f$ and $g$ are continuous on domain $D$, then so are $f+g. f-g, f\cdot g$ etc or that $f/g$ is continuous on $D-\{0\}$ and so forth. It is a pointless exercise to go all the way back to the definition to prove the continuity of multiply compound functions rather than use intermediate theorems of continuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that might help you out is the triangle inequality. Letting $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{e^{5x}+e^x+1},$ we can use triangle inequality to show that $$\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|\leq \dfrac{\left|e^{5x+x_0}-e^{5x_0+x}\right|+\left|e^{x}-e^{x_{0}}\right|}{\left|(e^{5x}+e^x+1)(e^{5x_{0}}+e^{x_{0}}+1)\right|},$$ since $e^{x_0+x}-e^{x+x_0}=0.$ Note that we can rewrite the right hand side as $$\dfrac{e^{x+x_0}\left|e^{4x}-e^{4x_0}\right|+\left|e^{x}-e^{x_{0}}\right|}{(e^{5x}+e^x+1)(e^{5x_{0}}+e^{x_{0}}+1)}.$$ Now use the fact that $x\mapsto e^{4x}$ and $x\mapsto e^x$ are both continuous, and show that $\frac{e^{x+x_0}}{(e^{5x}+e^x+1)(e^{5x_{0}}+e^{x_{0}}+1)}$ is bounded near $f(x_0)^2$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $x_0.$ Use that to show that for any $\epsilon>0,$ we can find $\delta>0$ such that $\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta.$

Alternatively, if you know that finite sums of continuous functions are again continuous, and that the quotient of a continuous function by a non-zero continuous function is continuous, then you're already done, once you can show that $e^{5x}+e^x+1>0$ for all $x.$